# What is a roller ball?

Tags: meaning

I am translating an english lecture (original not in writing) where the speaker gives "roller ball" as a simple example for something "you can touch to learn about it". (so the baseball-meaning will not apply)
The lecture is from the sixties, so the "rollerball" pen was not in broad use, I guess.
There was the proposal that it refers to the ball from a ball-bearing, but it confuses me a bit, as a roller is usually cylindrcal thats why one makes the difference between roller-bearing and ball-bearing.
It would make sense, if one would call a bearing also a "roller", but nowhere I did find this use... 
So I hope it doesn't seem too pedantic and someone can give me an estimation what a "roller ball" is likely to be in this exemple.

Ist basically "if you teach him about roller balls, give him a roller ball" ( you know, as opposed to just teaching theoretical about something)

Comment: Can you provide the exact quote, perhaps with some context? Given the timeframe it's not referring to a ball mouse or (as you said) a roller pen, but it could be referring to something like a [massager](https://books.google.com/books?id=8xQ3AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=%22These+arms+move+up+and+down+very+rapidly,+carrying+a+great+number+of+elastic+rubber+roller+balls%22).

Comment: Hello, Klaus, and welcome to EL&U. I would like to help you edit your question, but I have a few questions of my own: could you provide either more context or the exact quote?

Comment: You say "(original not in writing)" so did you *mis-hear* the **roller ball** that you think was said?

Comment: No, did not mis-hear it, just mentionned this because it could also be in one word or if a brand name, capitalized, but as I said, don't think so.

Comment: Absent context, there's no way to tell with any certainty.  Aml's suggestion of a "[track ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackball)" is probably the closest, though that device was in common use (among techies) for maybe a year before someone turned it upside down and created the "mouse".  (But you say the lecture was from the 60s, and none of these device really got out of the labs until the 70s.)

Comment: I doubt it's possible to say what the lecturer was talking about without further information. I can't think of any correlation between "roller ball" and "you can touch to learn about it" either. However, "*roll a ball*" does sound somewhat plausible in the limited context.

Answer (score -2):

In this context Roller Ball is the original term for what is now called a Track Ball -- a pointing device that works like an upside down mechanical Mouse.  It was invented in the late 1940s and saw wider use beginning in the 1960s.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this reference, but only found that it was used in military (radar) applications that time end even as a secret, so I wonder, if this would be a good exemple in such a lecture ... you know "if you teach him about roller balls, give him a roller ball"... unless you could say that the knowledge about this "Roller Ball" was to some degree popular.

Comment: True -- I didn't see a roller ball until the 1970s (video arcade games), but it definitely fits the idea of learning to use it by playing with it.

Comment: Yea, me too, I would have liked this meaning, but the lecture is from 1964.

Comment: The radar usage was no longer secret after the 1950s, so it might have been a popular leading edge idea in academic circles in the 1960s.  Arrays of rollerballs (bearings) are also used like conveyor belts when you need to rotate items or change their direction of motion.